# How can I use onTouchEvent() in softkeyboard?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I know that `onTouchEvent()`
can return the current touch point's x,y in a `view`,
However, when I touch a key on a `softkeyboard`.
the method is not working,

My question is how can I apply `onTouchEvent` to `softkeyboard` on Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to get a touch event for a soft keyboard.

If you want to capture keys as they are entered into an `EditText`, check out the `EditText.addTextChangedListener()` function.

Alternatively, try implementing the `View.OnKeyListener` interface in your `Activity`, or overriding `public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e)`, or overriding `public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)`. In all of those cases, you can check what the `keyCode` or `KeyEvent` is and handle it as you wish.